# what is CTS host pc configurations?

Tags: android, android-source, cts

I am try to run cts with 16gb ram and 350gb hardisk of host machine but it fails frequently could you plz tell me the actual configuration for running cts.

Comment: Some machine requirements are listed here: https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/setup#desktop_setup

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found that there is no particular requirements for cts Host machine to run cts. you just have to install Linux 64bit and usb port.

Answer (score 0):

**Caution**: CTS currently supports 64-bit Linux and Mac OS host machines. CTS will not work on Windows OS.

you need 64-bit Linux or Mac OS in your host machine

Answer (score 0):

Linux Host machine configuration looks fine, Check whether JAVA 1.8 and above is installed and also set the adb and aapt file within the environment variables path to avoid any setup related issues during CTS execution.